# Push notification gives error when on foreground react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an app in which i want to enable push notification with react native firebase. I have done all the manual setup. I'm getting the notification when the app is in background. But when it's in foreground it shows an error like: **_this.showAlert() is not a function** when the same thing is working for the background. Here's the AndroidManifest.xml and App.js code of mine:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPermission();
    this.createNotificationListeners(); //add this line
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationListener;
    this.notificationOpenedListener;
  }

  //
  async checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
      this.getToken();
    } else {
      this.requestPermission();
    }
  }

  async createNotificationListeners() {
    /*
    * Triggered when a particular notification has been received in foreground
    * */
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
      const { title, body } = notification;
      console.log('onNotification:');
      this.showAlert(title, body);
      alert('message');

      const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
        sound: 'sampleaudio',
        show_in_foreground: true,
      })
        .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
        .setTitle(notification.title)
        // .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
        .setBody(notification.body)
        // .setData(notification.data)
        .android.setChannelId('fcm_default_channel') // e.g. the id you chose above
        .android.setSmallIcon('@drawable/ic_launcher') // create this icon in Android Studio
        .android.setColor('#000000') // you can set a color here
        .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);
        

      firebase.notifications()
        .displayNotification(localNotification)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });


    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('fcm_default_channel', 'Demo app name', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.High)
      .setDescription('Demo app description')
      .setSound('sampleaudio.mp3');
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    /*
    * If your app is in background, you can listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
    * */
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      console.log('onNotificationOpened:');
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    /*
    * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
    * */
    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      console.log('getInitialNotification:');
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    }
    /*
    * Triggered for data only payload in foreground
    * */
    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
      //process data message
      console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
  }

  //3
  async getToken() {
    let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
    if (!fcmToken) {
      fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmToken) {
        // user has a device token
        console.log('fcmToken:', fcmToken);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
      }
    }
    console.log('fcmToken:', fcmToken);
  }

  //2
  async requestPermission() {
    try {
      await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      // User has authorised
      this.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      // User has rejected permissions
      console.log('permission rejected');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>instructions</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ppnoti">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
       <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>

  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
  <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
       notification message. -->
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/notificationColor" />


<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>

    <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
  <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am i missing here?

**Additional Information:**

- React Native version: "0.58.3"
- React Native Firebase version: "^5.2.1"

Comment: I don't see showAlert definition?

Comment: i just removed showAlert and its working fine although when i try to open the app from the foreground notification it shows the same error. Not really sure how to solve that. If the showAlert definition is needed then how its working perfect on background because i have used showAlert there too.

Comment: Try moving this to constructor of the Component "this.createNotificationListeners();"

Comment: Result is still the same. When i try to open the app from the foreground notification it shows the error this.showAlert() is not a function. For background notification it's fine. Any suggestion how to solve that? @AshwinMothilal

Answer (score 1):

just add  showAlert function :

```
showAlert(title, body) {
 Alert.alert(
  title, body,
  [
    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
  ],
  { cancelable: false },
 );
}
```